# Unable to locate element ID - NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium

when im trying to select from a drop-down menu im getting the above error ..
the code i'm trying to use :

```
group = Select(web.find_element(by=By.ID, value='single_select62d3083e1707239'))
group.select_by_visible_text ('COHEEL_IPC-A-620_2207101059')
```

[this is how it looks when I inspect the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Mm4.png)

Thanks for the time :)

Comment: Check if the XPath is not changing based on input - it may changes after input compared to blank.

Comment: Also, make sure that the element isn't added after the page loads, because if that's the case you need to make sure you wait until the element is known to exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xpath to locate the element.
Try the following Xpath -

```
//label[contains(text(),'Separate groups')]/following-sibling::select
```

The code would look like -

```
sel = web.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Separate groups')]/following-sibling::select")
sel.select_by_visible_text('COHEEL_IPC-A-620_2207101059')
```